# Direct memory access of C++ DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

I have searched stackoverflow for this problem but didn't find this exact one. In particular, I've found a ton of questions regarding retrieving C++ string references (char**) when the C# side is managing the memory but not the other way around.

The situation is as follows. I have a DLL (written on VC++ 2012) which I wrote myself. It loads and parses data from files and then lets anyone using the DLL access this data (by actual direct memory access for performance reasons) in several ways. Any program in C++ using this DLL has obviously no problems doing that. C# as it seems does...

A bit of context:

The DLL provides exported functions accepting char** (arrays of char*) parameters whose elements are being set to memory locations in the DLL and then further processed by the DLL's user after the call.

An example might look like this (examplatory implementation):

```
int myFunction(char* dataArray[], int row)
{
    for (int i= 0; i < _something; ++i)
    {
        dataArray[i] = _some_char_ptr
    }
}
```

And this is what the callee's implementation might look like in C++:

```
char** data = new char*[__num_fields];

myFunction(data, __some_row);

for (int i= 0; i < __something; ++i)
{
    cout << data[i] << endl;
}
```

Special - thus different from all questions I found - about this is that the callee allocates a list of char* which after the call point to memory locations allocated by the DLL itself.

Now, I must say, I'm only using C# because you can get quite simple GUIs in notime. The C# GUI tool I'm working on is for integrity testing data the DLL loads. I'm not profound of C# at all. What I've tried so far wasn't successful at all and I'm aware there might be no solution for this problem due to C# not having any sort of pointer concepts. Similar problems I found in Java while using JNA to load DLLs there which led to me not using Java for such testing purposes anymore.

Now a bit of C# stuff I've tried, incl. context:

```
public static class DLLTest
{
    // delegate object for the function:
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate int MyFunction_Type(out string[] dataArray, int row);

    public static MyFunction_Type MyFunction { get; private set; }

    public static void Load()
    {
        IntPtr dllAddress = DllUtilities.LoadLibrary(@"__dll_path");
        IntPtr procAddress = DllUtilities.GetProcAddress(dllAddress, "myFunction");
        MyFunction = (MyFunction_Type)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(procAddress, typeof(MyFunction_Type));
    }
}
```

I'm then calling the function like this:

```
string[] data = new string[__num_fields];
DLLTest.MyFunction(out data, __row)
```

Code similar to this using things like normal strings, integers, booleans whatsoever work like a charm. Just these string arrays keep bugging me :-)

Note: I can't change the way the DLL works because I wrote this for my boss and he's using it fine in both C++ and Delphi programs. It performs well and we're not about to change anything on the DLL itself as it really is fine the way it is.

Any help or clarification is highly appreciated, thanks a lot, Greetings

Comment: `CallingConvention.StdCall` why?

Comment: That's a copy-paste line from the internet. I'm exporting the functions of the DLL using 'extern "C"' which makes use of stdcall calling conventions and thus disables name mangling. This exact line also stands on all the other DLL functions which work.

Comment: `extern "C"` disables C++ mangling. It doesn't set the calling convention.

Comment: On x64 Std and C are the same convention, but on x86 they are different so the C# must match the C++ declaration

Comment: This is very dangerous code, your C++ code can easily destroy the GC heap because it has no idea how long the passed array really is.  It needs to know __num_fields to do it safely, it doesn't.  There's also a significant memory management problem, those strings need to be released again and the C# code cannot do that.  Don't do this.

Comment: @HansPassant I know it is. But the answer why I'm using it like this is simple: The DLL itself tells what __num_fields is in another call. Unless the user hasn't requested __num_fields prior to such a data aquisition call, the DLL will return erroneous. I'm conveniently moving the responsibilities about memory to the user. It's ugly but it's okay the way we're using this DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out string[] dataArray
```

is the wrong translation for the `char**` parameter. It should be:

```
IntPtr[] dataArray
```

The calling C# code then allocates the array before calling the function. Just as the C++ code does.

```
IntPtr[] data = new IntPtr[__num_fields];
int retval = DLLTest.MyFunction(data, __row);
```

You can then access the memory to your hearts content using the `Marshal` class to read the unmanaged memory behind the `IntPtr` pointers.

The calling convention looks a bit odd. As written, the C++ function is `cdecl`. As Hans says, there must also be some mechanism for the DLL to know how long the passed in array is.

Comment: every exported function in the DLL has this prefix: extern "C" __declspec(dllexport). I didn't put it here for readability.

Comment: @poljpocket That's fine. The functions are still `__cdecl` unless you explicitly write `__stdcall`.

Comment: You are asking how the DLL can supply pointers to its memory. And that means the DLL has to give you those pointers in the form of `IntPtr`. The functions that read from unmanaged memory can be found in the `Marshal` class. They all accept `IntPtr`.

Comment: By the way, you might consider Delphi VCL for your GUI since you already have code to access the DLL from Delphi. It's probably easier to use pointers with than C#, and quite effective at GUI building. On the other hand, if you don't like Pascal, then it probably doesn't matter how good it is!!

Comment: **Perfect!** thanks a lot! I successfully got my lists from the DLL just now!

Comment: Oh I'm using Delphi day in day out. I just wanted to try out new stuff and one reason for all this also was that we have clients having problems using our DLLs in their C# programs. So I was ordered to learn about C# :-)